# Edit multiple JPanels in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have 50 JPanels in one JFrame and I want all of them to be the same size. I'm using the gui builder in netbeans and cant seem to figure out if there is an easy way to edit the dimensions of all JPanels simultaneously? I remember reading somewhere that there is a feature that makes this possible but can't find any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the GUI Builder, you should be able to select multiple components by pressing and holding the CTRL key while clicking on them. if the components share a same property, such as preffered size or size, you will be able to edit the value for all of them at the same time.

By modifying the prefferedSize Property on the properties view, and pressing enter after you set the width and height, all of the JPanels should pop to the same width and height.

Another way to do it, is to select all of the JPanels holding CTRL and clicking on them, then right click on one of them while all of them are selected and there are some options such as "same size" or "set default size"

Answer (score 2):

Use the right layout.  For this case, `GridLayout` seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Select all of the panels (might be easiest to do it in the navigator) then right click and do Same Size > Same Width then Same Size > Same Height. It will set them to the largest dimension of the selected panels.

If you want to set a specific size, change the preferredSize property while all panels are selected.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make an abstract JPanel where you set the preferred size, and all the rest extend this?